# ORA-38106: MERGE not supported on join view or view with INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, select, merge

How do I merge into a view with multiple tables. 
My issue is that only when child, parent table join, I can determine the match condition to merge and just with single table I can't.

I am getting ORA-38106: MERGE not supported on join view or view with INSTEAD OF trigger

```
create table t (id number, c varchar2(10));
create table p (p_id number, id number);

merge into (select t.c, p.p_id from t, p  where t.id = p.id) t 
     using (select 1 id from dual) d 
        ON (t.p_id = d.id) 
      when matched then update set c = 'iii';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the logic in to the `using` query.  I think this does what you intend:

```
merge into t t 
     using (select p_id from p where p_id = 1) d 
        ON (t.p_id = d.p_id) 
      when matched then update set c = 'iii';
```

Comment: Yes. Just a small change.  ON (t.id = d.p_id) should be ON (t.p_id = d.p_id). Thanks